# Generic Regular expression in Perl for the following text

Tags: regex, perl

I need  to match the following text with a regular expression in Perl.

```
PS3XAY3N5SZ4K-XX_5C9F-S801-F04BN01K-00000-00
```

The expression that I have written is:

```
(\w+)\-(\w+)\-(\w+)\-(\w+)\-(\w+)\-(\w+)
```

But I want something more generic. By generic what I mean is I want to have any number of hyphens (`-`) in it.

Maybe there is something like `if - then` in regex, i.e. if some character is present then look for some other thing. Can anyone please help me out?

More about my problem:

AB-ab 
abc-mno-xyz 
lmi-jlk-mno-xyz 
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
 and so on...!

I wish to match all patterns.. to be more precise my string(feel free to use \w Since I can have uppercase , lowercase , numeric and '_'underscore here.) can be considered as a set of any number of  alphanumeric substrings with hyphen('-') as a delimiter

Comment: If all you want is match the whole string, use something like `my ($id) = /([w+-]+_[\w-]+)/`. If you need all of the components without knowing how many there are, you can do `my @parts = split(/[_-]/, $id)`.

Comment: This will match strings like AB-BX-
- at the end

Comment: That's easy to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a regex with quatifiers (see [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) - Section Quantifiers).

You have several possibilities:

- `/\w+(?:-\w+)+)/` will match any two groups of `\w` characters if linked by a hyphen (`-`). For example, `AB-CD` will match. Pay attention that with `\w` you are matching upper and lower case letters, so you will also match a word like `pre-owned` as key.
- `/\w+(?:-\w+){5})/` will match keys with exactly 6 groups. It's equivalent to the one you have
- `/\w+(?:-\w+){5,})/` will match keys with 6 groups or more.

If there are more than one key in the document, you can do an implicit loop in the regex with the `/g` option.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw{say};
use Data::Dumper;    

my $text = "some text here PS3XAY3N5SZ4K-XX_5C9F-S801-F04BN01K-00000-00 some text there";

my @matches = $text =~ /\w+(?:-\w+)+)/g;

print Dumper(\@matches);
```

Result:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'PS3XAY3N5SZ4K-XX_5C9F-S801-F04BN01K-00000-00'
        ];
```

Comment: What I actually need to do is , The string mentioned above will be present in a large text file I need to extract that and store it into a variable. Though I can use the array and join it later but I am looking for something better in the regular expression only

Comment: @YatiSawhney I've edited. Anyhow, I suggest you edit your question with more context regarding _what_, _where_ and _how_ you want to match that text. I'm making some assumptions: e.g. what is the minimum number of groups that constitute a key... I assume ABC-DEF is a valid match, for example.

Comment: Thanks I got it ..!

Answer (score 0):

How about using split:

```
my $str = 'PS3XAY3N5SZ4K-XX_5C9F-S801-F04BN01K-00000-00';
my @elem = split(/-/, $str);
```

**Edit according to comments:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
use Modern::Perl;

my $str = 'Text before PS3XAY3N5SZ4K-XX_5C9F-S801-F04BN01K-00000-00 text after';
my ($str2) = $str =~  /(\w+(?:-\w+)+)/;
my @elem = split(/-/, $str2);
say Dumper\@elem;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'PS3XAY3N5SZ4K',
          'XX_5C9F',
          'S801',
          'F04BN01K',
          '00000',
          '00'
        ];
```

Comment: Point it .. a needed a regex to extract the above string which is a large text file of about 10MB
Once I can extract it I can play around with it. Its all about extraction of  strings like 'PS3XAY3N5SZ4K-XX_5C9F-S801-F04BN01K-00000-00' like I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @YatiSawhney: OK, I see. Then use a combination of the two answers, the one from eballes followed by mine.

Comment: Thanks a lot..! :)